# Kernel of linear transformation in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $T: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be a linear transformation satisfying
\begin{align*}
T(0,1,1) =& (-1,1,1) \\
T(1,0,1) =& (1,-1,1) \\
T(1,1,0) =& (1,-1,0) .
\end{align*}

Is it necessary true that $\ker(T) = \operatorname{Sp}\{(1,-1,1)\}$ ?
Well, I tried to say that we know that $\operatorname{Im}(T) = \operatorname{Sp}\{T(0,1,1),\,T(1,0,1),\,T(1,1,1)\}$

So, $\operatorname{Im}(T) = \operatorname{Sp}\{(-1,1,1),\,(1,-1,1),\,(1,-1,0)\}$ which means $\operatorname{Sp}\{(1,-1,1)\} \in \operatorname{Im}(T)$
and also $(1,1,1)$ is linearly independent by $2$ other vectors which are in $\operatorname{Im}(T)$.

Now, how can I prove that $\operatorname{Sp}\{(1,1,1)\}$ not inside $\ker(T)$? or maybe $\operatorname{Sp}\{(1,1,1)\} \in \ker (T)$  which makes it $\operatorname{Sp}\{(1,1,1)\} = \ker (T)$?

Comment: Hint: use the dimensions' theorem to show $\;\dim \ker T=1\;$ ...

Comment: I did show that $dimImT = 2$, and because $dimR^3 = 3$. Thus, $dimKerT=1$. and because of that I can say that $(1,-1,1)$ CAN be a basis to $KerT$. Thus, it can be in its span because it's a sub-space of $R^3$ and also a basis to $KerT$. Thus, $KerT = Sp(\{1,-1,1)\})$

Comment: Thank you very much @DonAntonio

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, are you sure I can say that? I think I need to show somehow that T(Sp(\{(1,-1,1)\}) = 0 and then I can say that it equals to $KerT$. but how can I show that? Or am I all wrong and what I wrote is enough?

Comment: Of course you must show that vector is in the kernel, Ilan!! I thought you already did that...I didn´t check that.

Comment: Well, how can I check that it's in $KerT$ then? I'm not sure :(

Comment: We can go to that chat if you prefer,I really want to get that question done, thanks in advance @DonAntonio !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply put our vectors in the matrix and do row operations in the following way - we are trying to get a basis in the right part:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 &-1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &-1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)\sim
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 &-1 & 1 & 1\\
0 &-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)\sim
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 &-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)\sim
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0\\
0 &-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)\sim
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0\\
0 &-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$$

What have we found out by doing this?

Notice that at the beginning we have $a|b$, where $T(a)=b$ in each row. This property is not changed using row operations.

So we see that $T(1,3,0)=(0,0,0)$. This means that $(1,3,0)\in\operatorname{Ker} T$.

We have also found out that the image is generated by the vectors $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. (If we look only on the right part, then we have tried to row reduce the matrix consisting of images of basis vectors.) Since these vectors are linearly independent, we get that $\dim\operatorname{Im} T =2$. By rank-nullity theorem we know that $\dim\operatorname{Ker} T=1$.

Comment: So now because of $dimKerT = 1$ I can assume that $Sp(\{(1,-1,1)\}) \in KerT$ which means $Sp(\{(1,-1,1)\}) = KerT$

Comment: Why do you keep saying that $(1,-1,1)$ is in kernel? If I did not make a mistake, I have computed above that $\operatorname{Ker} T=\operatorname{Sp}\{(1,3,0)\}$, so clearly $(1,-1,1)$ does not belong there. I have also tried to compute $T(1,-1,1)$ [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15830561#15830561). Again, I might have made mistake, but the result I got is not zero vector.

Comment: So $KerT \ne Sp(\{1,-1,1)\})$ ?

Comment: In another words: The vectors $(1,3,0)$ and $(1,-1,1)$ are linearly independent. So if we know that the dimension of kernel is one, they cannot be both in the kernel.

Comment: Yes, I am saying that $\operatorname{Ker}T= \operatorname{Sp}\{(1,3,0)\} \ne\operatorname{Sp}\{(1,-1,1)\}$.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix associated to $T$ with respect to the basis $\mathscr{B}=\{(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,0)\}$ on the domain and the canonical basis on the codomain is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix associated to $T$ with respect to the canonical basis on both the domain and the codomain is
$$
B=AS^{-1}
$$
where
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
S^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
3/2 & -1/2 & -1/2 \\
-3/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Can you compute the null space of $B$? That is, the set of vectors $v$ such that $Bv=0$, which is the kernel of $T$.

Comment: Too complicated to understand, I'll stick to Don's answer. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Let the basis for the domain be $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}=\{(0,1,1),\;(1,0,1),\;(1,1,0)\}$. Let $w_1,w_2,w_3$ be the respective images of $v_i's$ under $T$.

A simple observation shows that: the set $\{w_1, w_2\}$ is linearly independent (as they are not multiples of each other) whereas $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ is a dependent set because $w_1-w_2+2w_3=0$. This means the dimension of the range space is exactly $2$, hence the kernel will be of dimension $1$ (by the rank-nullity theorem).

In fact we can now get the basis vector for the kernel as well:

Since $w_1-w_2+2w_3=0$, this means $T(v_1-v_2+2v_3)=0$. Thus the vector $v_1-v_2+2v_3=(1, 3, 0)$ forms the basis of the kernel.

Comment: if the base of Kernel is $(1,3,0)$ , how can I show that $KerT = Sp(1,-1,1)$ ?

Comment: The kernel of $T$ does not contain the vector $(1,-1,1)$. In fact you can verify that $$T(1,-1,1)=(3/2, -3/2, 1) \neq (0,0,0)$$.

Answer (score 2):

You know that ${\rm im}\; f=\langle (-1,1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,-1,0)\rangle$. This is the same as
 $$\langle (-1,1,1)\color{red}{+(1,-1,0)},(1,-1,1),(1,-1,0)\rangle=\langle (0,0,1),(1,-1,1),(1,-1,0)\rangle$$ which in turn is the same as $$\langle (0,0,1),(1,-1,1)\color{blue}{-(0,0,1)},(1,-1,0)\rangle=\langle (0,0,1),(1,-1,0),(1,-1,0)\rangle$$

Thus the dimension of the image is $2$. By the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the kernel is $1$. It follows that if you find $v\in\ker T$ nonzero, $\langle v\rangle =\ker T$. Can you check whether $(1,-1,1)\in \ker T$?

Comment: That's exactly what there is left to find, how can I find that $v \in KerT$ and see that it's $(1,-1,1) \in KerT$? I did manage to find KerT base which is (1,3,0) but it doesn't give me anything. Can you edit your answer and show me how to find that v? Much appreciated!

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Yes, it gives you all you need. You know $\ker T$ is **one dimensional** thus **any** nonzero vector in it spans $\ker T$.

Comment: Oh, so because $dimKerT = 1$ I can assume that if $v \ne 0 $then $v \in KerT$. Thus, if $v = (1,-1,1)$ then I can say that $Sp(1,-1,1) \in KerT$ . Thus, $Sp(1,-1,1) = KerT$ . But other people here told me I still need to prove it and I can't assume that even if $dimKerT = 1$.

Comment: No. That is wrong. What you can say is that if $v\neq 0$ **and** $\color{red}{v\in\ker T}$ **then** $\ker T=\langle v\rangle$.

Comment: and $v \ne 0$ is true because its basis isn't $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Oh, I'm so stupid, I got it now! Only because it has one dimension thus any nonzero vector CAN span it so $Sp(1,-1,1)$ can be in $KerT.$

Comment: No, the only nonzero vectors that can span a one dimensional subspace are those **in** that subspace.

Comment: Martin just gave a good answer! Yey.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

Choose the basis $B = \{(0,1,1),\;(1,0,1),\;(1,1,0)\}$.

What does the matrix representation $[T]^B_E$ of the linear map $T$ with respect to the bases $B$ and $E$ (the standard basis) look like?

Recall that the kernel of a matrix is invariant under basis transformation.

Comment: If I find that matrix, how will that matrix help me?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Then we can determine its kernel and answer those questions concerning the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the vector $\;(111)\;$ wrt the usual, canonical basis, first write it as a linear combination of the given basis:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1\\-1\\\;1\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\iff$$

$$\begin{align*}b+c=1\\{}\\a+c=-1\\{}\\a+b=1\end{align*}\;\implies\;\;b-c=2\implies b=\frac32\;,\;\;a=c=-\frac12$$

Thus we get

$$T\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\frac12\left(-T\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}+3T\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}-T\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\right)=\ldots$$

If the above is zero you've found one non-zero element in the kernel and thus a basis for it, otherwise you need to find *another* vector that *actually* is in the kernel.

Comment: I'm still confused, why finding $T(1,1,1)$ when we need to find $T(1,-1,1)$? and also why do I need to multiply all of them by 0.5 and lastly, the equation you built equals to$ T(1,1,1) = (1.5,-1.5,1)$, but I still don't understand how it helps to find $(1,-1,1) \in KerT$

Comment: Also, I did manage to find that (1,3,0) is a basis to KerT according to  Anurag's answer. but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Tyop, Ilan: typo.